# process of inserting into multiple tables from one form

Tags: sql

I have a question. Lets say i have a form and that form might insert into 3 table Table1,Table2 and Table3. Table2 and Table3 has relation with Table1. Table1 must get some data. but Table2 and Table3 might or might not. my question is , should i not insert data's into table2 and table3 when not needed or rather make the entry but remain fields empty.?

Comment: No need to insert data that doesn't exist.

Comment: Don't insert "blank values" if you don't need them. That's what `LEFT/RIGHT JOIN` (amongst others) is for in SQL.

Comment: wont i have problem while editing the form. as if user wants to add something on edit, table2 or table 3 might work as insert